# Problem deploying Streamlit app with Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, streamlit

Problem when trying to deploy my streamlit app on Heroku. The error shows:

```
2021-01-31T08:05:31.912498+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=tweetsenitments.herokuapp.com request_id=11d4b0d8-5f39-40ee-8394-ea9dafe591d0 fwd="103.120.57.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-31T08:05:32.461450+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tweetsenitments.herokuapp.com request_id=a32d26d8-0ca6-429e-b785-a5ee037c0e56 fwd="103.120.57.242" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My Procfile is as shown:

```
web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py
```

My Setup.sh file is as shown:

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/
echo "\
[general]\n\
email = \"nshnt1999@gmail.com\"\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/credentials.toml
echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableCORS=false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

I've tried a few different suggestions I've found, like removing the space between web: and sh in Procfile,but no luck so far. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Github Link:** https://github.com/nshnt1999/TwitterSentimentAnalysis

Comment: You probably need to add the PORT, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64514388/9095551

Comment: Tried that as well doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Koi toh bata do plzzz!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ7rGcE766k
[1]: https://github.com/Blues1998/Streamlit-hello-app

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/

echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
port = $PORT\n\
enableCORS = false\n\
\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```