# Error in deploying webapp in heroku made by streamlit

Tags: github, heroku, python-3.8, streamlit

I've uploaded all file dependencies of the web app made with streamlit into the github.
Repo link : https://github.com/sagnik1511/Lifely

But when I'm trying to deploy this project into Heroku it deploys correctly and when I am opening the webpage it shows error :

""" Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail """

Please anybody help :(

Comment: Maybe the port is missing, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64514388/9095551

Comment: @BeppeC Thanks . I didn't know about it before so, I haven't changed that. Thanks again :)