# H10 Error When Deploying Streamlit Dashboard to Heroku Server

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, streamlit

I have created a simple ML dashboard app that I would like to deploy using Heroku. I used Streamlit to develop the dashboard. The dashboard runs properly when executed locally.

When I run it using Heroku, I receive the following logs/errors:

```
    2021-05-20T18:00:47.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user dorrego.cabrera@gmail.com
    2021-05-20T18:01:54.482407+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 573b33a2 by user dorrego.cabrera@gmail.com
    2021-05-20T18:01:54.482407+00:00 app[api]: Release v4 created by user dorrego.cabrera@gmail.com
    2021-05-20T18:01:54.720695+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2021-05-20T18:02:16.914037+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py`
    2021-05-20T18:02:27.832874+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2021-05-20T18:02:27.832912+00:00 app[web.1]:  Welcome to Streamlit!
    2021-05-20T18:02:27.832912+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2021-05-20T18:02:27.832917+00:00 app[web.1]: If you're one of our development partners or you're interested in getting
    2021-05-20T18:02:27.832918+00:00 app[web.1]: personal technical support or Streamlit updates, please enter your email
    2021-05-20T18:02:27.832924+00:00 app[web.1]: address below. Otherwise, you may leave the field blank.
    2021-05-20T18:02:27.832924+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2021-05-20T18:02:27.833121+00:00 app[web.1]: Email: 2021-05-20 18:02:27.832
    2021-05-20T18:02:28.117610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
    2021-05-20T18:02:28.586088+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2021-05-20T18:02:28.589400+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2021-05-20T18:02:32.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2021-05-20T18:02:47.575726+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py`
    2021-05-20T18:03:05.221238+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2021-05-20T18:03:05.221259+00:00 app[web.1]:  Welcome to Streamlit!
    2021-05-20T18:03:05.221259+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2021-05-20T18:03:05.221260+00:00 app[web.1]: If you're one of our development partners or you're interested in getting
    2021-05-20T18:03:05.221260+00:00 app[web.1]: personal technical support or Streamlit updates, please enter your email
    2021-05-20T18:03:05.221261+00:00 app[web.1]: address below. Otherwise, you may leave the field blank.
    2021-05-20T18:03:05.221261+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2021-05-20T18:03:05.221570+00:00 app[web.1]: Email: 2021-05-20 18:03:05.221
    2021-05-20T18:03:05.699001+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 255
    2021-05-20T18:03:05.814822+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2021-05-20T18:08:32.862231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secret-peak-69981.herokuapp.com request_id=dd7383d9-87a7-4004-b332-ea4426e9a831 fwd="73.170.73.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
    2021-05-20T18:08:33.588085+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=secret-peak-69981.herokuapp.com request_id=6a6ce7a2-ecc6-49ae-98b4-4cd7f27319fd fwd="73.170.73.198" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My **Procfile** looks good:

`web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run app.py`

Here's the **setup.sh** code:

```
mkdir -p ~/.streamlit

echo "\
[genera]\n\
email = \"dorrego.cabrera@gmail.com\"\n\
"> ~/.streamlit/credentials.toml

echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
enableXsrfProtection = false\n\
enableCORS = false\n\
port = $PORT\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

It seems like the code installs Streamlit twice. Can someone explain why?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64514388/9095551. I think you need to define `server.port`

Comment: Thanks, Beppe! That post discusses an R10 error. However, I am encountering an H10 error. Also, I'm not experiencing a boot timeout.