# what do I need to change in my setup file to get it to connect to the port?

Tags: heroku

It says " Starting process with command `sh setup.sh && streamlit run dashboard.py -- server.port 14549`"
And the port switches everytime I deploy so I can't set port as a set number.
my error message I when I type in "heroku logs --tail -a appname" I got error message:
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
Here is my code
'''

```
   mkdir -p ~/.streamlit/
echo "\
[server]\n\
headless = true\n\
port = $PORT\n\
enableCORS = true\n\
\n\
" > ~/.streamlit/config.toml
```

'''

Comment: "the port switches everytime I deploy so I can't set port as a set number"—right, that's how it's supposed to work. You need to use the port given by the `PORT` environment variable, and based on the message you show here it looks like you're already doing that. I don't know anything about streamlit, but I suggest you look earlier in your logs for more information.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64514388/9095551