# Heroku + Streamlit Python App sh: 0: Can't open setup.sh

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

I am very new to both Heroku and Streamlit, and have hit a bit of a snag. I am trying to deploy a python app, but I receive an application error saying my page could not be served. I checked my logs, and I see the information posted below:

```
2022-01-04T22:11:02.604033+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `sh setup.sh && streamlit run fvus-dashboard-app.py`
2022-01-04T22:11:04.060268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2022-01-04T22:11:04.121148+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-01-04T22:11:03.890791+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 0: Can't open setup.sh
2022-01-04T22:21:26.983595+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yearly-fvus-streamlit.herokuapp.com request_id=344c6b88-39b8-4741-bc95-63fd0ca4759e fwd="173.25.202.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-01-04T22:21:26.788594+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=yearly-fvus-streamlit.herokuapp.com request_id=32ce7fb0-ca7f-4262-bc8e-71f8d6a3d6bc fwd="173.25.202.25" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I have a Procfile in which I use:

```
web sh setup.sh && streamlit run fvus-dashboard-app.py
```

If I understand things correctly, the problem is that `setup.sh` can't be opened. I don't know what to do to fix that, though. Has anyone seen this before and can perhaps push me in the correct direction?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64514388/9095551

Answer (score 0):

web: sh setup.sh && streamlit run fvus-dashboard-app.py

This is the correct code for setup.sh . By mistake you have missed a colon
Hope it works now :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).